# node js app engine github trigger builds not getting published to development?

Tags: node.js, git, google-cloud-platform, gpc

I have a node.js website that runs locally fine with `node server.js`. I added a Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:carbon    
VOLUME ["/root"]    
# Create app directory  
WORKDIR /usr/src/app    
# Install app dependencies  
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied   
# where available (npm@5+)  
COPY package*.json ./   
RUN npm install 
# If you are building your code for production  
# RUN npm install --only=production 
# Bundle app source 
COPY . .    
EXPOSE 8080 
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

And if I deploy my app with `gcloud app deploy` I can get it accessible online via a url. I believe my project is an 'App Engine' project? If I run subsequent `gcloud app deploy` commands, my new code gets pushed to the online site. But I can't get github master commits trigger and publish a new build.

I tried adding a trigger so that everytime new code gets added to my public github repo master branch, it gets sent to my production URL. [image]

Full Trigger:
[image]

So I merge a PR into the master branch of my github repo. I look in my build history and see there is a new build, clicking the commit takes me to the new pr I just merged into the master branch of my github repo.

[image]

But If I access my website url, the new code is not there. If I run `cloud app deploy` again eventually it will appear, my trigger seems to be working fine from the logs, why is my build not getting published?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might be with the fact that you're using a [Dockerfile](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/building/build-containers#build_using_a_build_config_file) instead of Cloud Build configuration file... Unless there's something else I'm not seeing.

Look [here](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart-triggering-builds-with-source-repositories#create_a_build_trigger) under the fourth step, fifth bullet, for the solution. It says:

> Under Build configuration, select Cloud Build configuration file.

Comment: thx, i added a cloudbuild.yaml and removed my Dockerfile, told the trigger to use cloudbuild.yaml intead, it was building but got stopped due to a timeout error. i tried adding a timeout field to the cloudbuild.yaml file but ended up somehow creating an infinite loop where builds keep getting triggered every second. my cloudbuild.yaml looks like this: `steps:
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy"]`

Comment: thx for the info, it helped me solve this ticket's bug but i made a new ticket for the new bug im facing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64190045/gcloud-nodejs-cloudbuild-yaml-stuck-in-infinite-loop